# Showing the effect of ngCloak

Tags: javascript, html, ngcloak

I am working with my friend on an application and we decided to use the *ngCloak* directive to avoid the display of raw/uncompiled code. Since we are both relatively new to this we would like to know if there's a way to capture the effect of what happens if the *ngCloak* directive is left out.

Since both of our computers are substantially powerful the effect is almost invincible. Is there a way to slow this down so that we will be able to see what would happen on a slower device?

Or even process the code step by step?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Having left out the ng-cloak, and assuming you are making a call to get the data being rendered soon after the page loads up, you can open the debugger in your browser and set a break point on the line that makes the call to get the data. Refresh the page and script will pause on your break point and you will see the effect of not using ng-cloak in the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

You could use emulator (like Android emulator) to view the effect.
I think that ngCloak won't work as you expected, because it does it works on the compile phase, before the binding happens.

You must probably write your own ngCloak, and do the job on the link phase. More information here https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsebastienollivier.fr%2Fblog%2Fangularjs%2Fpourquoi-il-ne-faut-pas-utiliser-ngcloak